# Can I make internal enum visible to the test project, and use it in public test method?

Tags: c#, enums, access-modifiers, internalsvisibleto

I have `internal enum MyEnum` in the project.
And I also have a custom attribute on some of the values of `MyEnum`, like:

```
internal enum MyEnum
{
    [CustomAttribute("value")]
    EnumValue,
}
```

My project also contains class `InternalsVisibleTo.cs`:
`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestProjectName")]`

And I'd like to cover this attribute in xUnit Theory, i.e.:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(MyEnum.EnumValue, "value")]
public void MyAttributeWorksCorrectly(MyEnum myEnum, string expectedAttributeValue) 
{
}
```

Because InternalsVisibleTo - InlineData has access to the enum.
However, I get the following error:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'MyTestProjectName.MyEnum' is less accessible than method 'MyAttributeWorksCorrectly'

Sure - this is violation.

Question - can I bypass it somehow without makine MyEnum `public`?

I've already read few articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...
I found out the workaround :/
It is a little bit silly to answer my own question.
Maybe the question should be reported for deletion?

Workaround:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(nameof(MyEnum.EnumValue), "value")]
public void MyAttributeWorksCorrectly(string nameOfEnumField, string expectedAttributeValue) 
{
    Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(nameOfEnumField);
}
```

I am curious what others think... Please share your thoughts...

Comment: Answering your own question on SO is fine :)
In my opinion is this workaround a little hacky and I personally wouldn't use it in Production Code, as there is no need for this hacky workaround, you can just declare this test as `internal` or use a `[Fact]`-UnitTest, you can take a look at my answer for that :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77448208/10826750
If you really want to keep the UnitTest publicly available this or the `[Fact]`-based approach would be the only possible solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

---

That is because you method `MyAttributeWorksCorrectly` is `public`, that means that anybody could call this method. But `MyEnum` is `internal` which means only the current assembly (and any assembly that you define with `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute) has access to this Type.

Think about that, what if your test assembly gets used by somebody else, and they want to call the Method `MyAttributeWorksCorrectly`, they would also know of the existence of `MyEnum` which they should not because of the `internal`-modifier. That is why the compiler does not let you compile.

You can fix this Issue by simply marking the UniTest as `internal` or by using a `[Fact]`-UnitTest, of course there you do not have the possibility with dynamic data.

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(
    MyEnum.EnumValue,
    "value"
)]
internal void Test1(MyEnum myEnum, string expectedValue)
{
    string? attributeValue = myEnum.GetType()
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMembers.First(
            x => x.Name == myEnum.ToString()
        )
        ?.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>(
            false
        )
        ?.Value;

    Assert.NotNull(
        attributeValue
    );

    Assert.Equal(
        expectedValue,
        attributeValue
    );
}

[Fact]
public void MyAttributeWorksCorrectly()
{
    const MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.EnumValue;

    string? attributeValue = myEnum.GetType()
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMembers.First(
            x => x.Name == myEnum.ToString()
        )
        ?.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>(
            false
        )
        ?.Value;

    Assert.NotNull(
        attributeValue
    );

    Assert.Equal(
        "value",
        attributeValue
    );
}
```